# How can I display array items using a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an item into an empty array using `.push` inside loop then display it again but nothing is happening. Below is my current code:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(){
   const canvasArray = [];
   $('.box').each(function(){
       var boxName = $(this).text();
       canvasArray.push(boxName);
   });
   console.log(canvasArray);
});
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
    <div class="box box-1">Red</div>
    <div class="box box-2">Blue</div>
    <div class="box box-3">Green</div>
    <div class="box box-4">Yellow</div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

In my console log, it returns something like this:

```
Array(4) [ "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow" ]
0: "Red"
1: "Blue"
2: "Green"
3: "Yellow"
length: 4
```

I want to display the value of my `canvasArray` and append it to a DIV and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$.each(canvasArray, function(index, value){
    $("#result").append(index + ": " + value + '<br>');
});
```

but nothing is happening and no error in my console log. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome. Please use the editor to put your code in a functioning snippet.

Comment: Code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/t3he1b9a/).   The reason for the suggestion of putting in a snippet (above) is so that we can see *how* you're using your code in context, eg on a click event but the event isn't defined correctly, or from an ajax call but you're trying to use canvasArray too soon.   As your `$.each` doesn't appear in context, it could be that you're trying to use it before canvasArray has been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. Here it is. Perhaps you were unsure how to structure it all?

In this demo, the `results` div is populated upon a second button press - but you could alternately just move the `$.each()` code up into the first button's click handler (below the console.log, for example).

```js
const canvasArray = [];
$('.button').on('click', function(){
   $('.box').each(function(){
       var boxName = $(this).text();
       canvasArray.push(boxName);
   });
   console.log(canvasArray);
});

$('.button2').on('click', function(){
  $.each(canvasArray, function(index, value){
    $("#result").append(index + ": " + value + '<br>');
  });
});
```

```css
#result{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top:20px;
  background:wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog">
    <div class="box box-1">Red</div>
    <div class="box box-2">Blue</div>
    <div class="box box-3">Green</div>
    <div class="box box-4">Yellow</div>
</div>

<button class="button">Populate Canvas Array</button>
<button class="button2">Write Into Results Div</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```